# What is the equivalent of CUME_DIST() in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, analytics

SQL Server 2012 seems to have introduced [CUME_DIST()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231078.aspx) and [PERCENT_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213573.aspx) which are used to compute the cumulative distribution of a column. Is there an equivalent function in SQL Server 2008 to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Never say never, in SQL.

The statement:

```
select percent_rank() over (partition by <x> order by <y>)
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
select row_number() over (partition by <x> order by <y>) / count(*) over (partition by <x>)
```

Essentially means that it works when there are no duplicates in the data.  It should be close enough even when there are duplicates.

The "real" answer is that it is equivalent to:

```
select row_number() over (partition by <x> order by <y>) / count(distinct <y>) over (partition by <x>)
```

But, we don't have count(distinct) as a function.  And, it is a pain to express in 2008, unless you really need to.

The function cume_dist() is harder because it requires a cumulative sum, and you need a self join for that.  The approximation assuming no duplicates:

```
with t as (select <x>, <y>,
                  row_number() over (partition by <x> order by <y>) as seqnum
           from <table>
          )
select t.*, sumy*1.0 / sum(sumy) over (partition by <x>)
from (select t.*, sum(tprev.y) as sumy
      from t left outer join
           t tprev
           on t.x = tprev.x and t.seqnum >= tprev.seqnum
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

No equivalent functions exist before 2012, but one possible workaround involves a recursive CTE, at least for data sets < 32767 rows. Here, a pair of dice is thrown 30 times:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @t TABLE(i INT);
DECLARE @i INT=0;

WHILE @i<30 BEGIN
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (CAST(RAND()*6 AS INT)+1 + CAST(RAND()*6 AS INT)+1);
    SET @i+=1;
END

DECLARE @tc INT; SELECT @tc=COUNT(*) FROM @t;

WITH a AS (
    SELECT *
    , d=CAST(COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY i ORDER BY i) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / @tc
    , r=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY i)
    , pr=CAST((RANK()OVER(ORDER BY i)-1)AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / (@tc - 1)
    FROM @t
)
, rcte (i, d, r, cd, pr) AS (
    SELECT i, d, r, d, pr
    FROM a
    WHERE r=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.i, a.d, a.r
    , CASE WHEN rcte.i<>a.i THEN CAST(rcte.cd+a.d AS DECIMAL(5,2)) ELSE rcte.cd END
    , a.pr
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN rcte ON rcte.r + 1 = a.r
)
SELECT i,cd,pr FROM rcte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Result:

```
i           cd                                      pr
----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
2           0.0333333333333                         0.0000000000000
3           0.0700000000000                         0.0344827586206
4           0.2400000000000                         0.0689655172413
4           0.2400000000000                         0.0689655172413
4           0.2400000000000                         0.0689655172413
4           0.2400000000000                         0.0689655172413
4           0.2400000000000                         0.0689655172413
5           0.3100000000000                         0.2413793103448
5           0.3100000000000                         0.2413793103448
6           0.3800000000000                         0.3103448275862
6           0.3800000000000                         0.3103448275862
7           0.5100000000000                         0.3793103448275
7           0.5100000000000                         0.3793103448275
7           0.5100000000000                         0.3793103448275
7           0.5100000000000                         0.3793103448275
8           0.6100000000000                         0.5172413793103
8           0.6100000000000                         0.5172413793103
8           0.6100000000000                         0.5172413793103
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
9           0.8400000000000                         0.6206896551724
10          0.8700000000000                         0.8620689655172
11          0.9700000000000                         0.8965517241379
11          0.9700000000000                         0.8965517241379
11          0.9700000000000                         0.8965517241379
12          1.0000000000000                         1.0000000000000
```

Below is the SQL 2012 equivalent to the above CTE:

```
SELECT *
, cd=CUME_DIST()OVER(ORDER BY i)
, pr=PERCENT_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY i)
FROM @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes very close. First some sample data:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.DartScores
(
    TournamentID INT,
    PlayerID INT,
    Score INT
);

INSERT dbo.DartScores VALUES
(1, 1, 320),
(1, 2, 340),
(1, 3, 310),
(1, 4, 370),
(2, 1, 310),
(2, 2, 280),
(2, 3, 370),
(2, 4, 370);
```

Now, the 2012 version of a query:

```
SELECT TournamentID, PlayerID, Score, 
  pr = PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TournamentID ORDER BY Score),
  cd = CUME_DIST()    OVER (PARTITION BY TournamentID ORDER BY Score)
FROM dbo.DartScores
ORDER BY TournamentID, pr;
```

Produces this result:

```
TournamentID PlayerID Score pr                  cd
1            3        310   0                   0.25
1            1        320   0.333333333333333   0.5
1            2        340   0.666666666666667   0.75
1            4        370   1                   1
2            2        280   0                   0.25
2            1        310   0.333333333333333   0.5
2            3        370   0.666666666666667   1
2            4        370   0.666666666666667   1
```

An equivalent for 2005 comes very close, but it doesn't handle ties very well. Sorry but I'm out of gas tonight otherwise I'd help figure out why. I know about as much as I've been able to learn from [Itzik's new High Performance window function book](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/04/26/new-book-microsoft-sql-server-2012-high-performance-t-sql-using-window-functions.aspx).

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TournamentID, PlayerID, Score,
     rk = RANK()   OVER (PARTITION BY TournamentID ORDER BY Score),
     rn = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TournamentID)
    FROM dbo.DartScores
)
SELECT TournamentID, PlayerID, Score,
  pr = 1e0*(rk-1)/(rn-1),
  cd = 1e0*(SELECT COALESCE(MIN(cte2.rk)-1, cte.rn)
    FROM cte AS cte2 WHERE cte2.rk > cte.rk) / rn
FROM cte;
```

Produces this result (notice how the cume_dist values change slightly for the ties):

```
TournamentID PlayerID Score pr                  cd
1            3        310   0                   0.25
1            1        320   0.333333333333333   0.5
1            2        340   0.666666666666667   0.75
1            4        370   1                   1
2            2        280   0                   0.25
2            1        310   0.333333333333333   0.5
2            3        370   0.666666666666667   0.75
2            4        370   0.666666666666667   0.75
```

Don't forget to clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.DartScores;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple solution, at least for the percent_rank() part. You can use

```
(rank() over (partition by <x> order by <y>)-1)/(count(*) over (partition by <x>)-1)
```

This will give you exactly the same result as

```
percent_rank() over (partition by <x> order by <y>)
```

The rank()-function is one of the few analytical functions that is already present in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: OP asks about CUME_DIST

Comment: ...and OP also asks about percent rank.